# onClickListener

Tags: java, android

Подскажите что не так,не реагируют кнопки на нажатие!

```
View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()){
                    case R.id.btnRed : Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Red",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();break;
                    case R.id.btnGreen : Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Green",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();break;
                    case R.id.btnBlue : Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Blue",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();break;
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: что у вас представляет собой View?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Подставляется ли Ваш onClickListener в setOnClickListener нужного View ? [View.html#setOnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener))

Comment: Точно! Невнимательность моя.Спасибо!